# problemas con el else

Tags: java

tengo problemas al colocar else directamente me aparece como error en esa linea

```
Scanner entra=new Scanner(System.in);
String DOMINATOR=entra.nextLine();
System.out.println("Le puedo ayudar en algo buen pana");
DOMINATOR=entra.nextLine();

if(DOMINATOR.equals("hola")==true);{
  System.out.println("bueno");
}else{
  System.out.println("esta mal");
}
```

Comment: Tienes un ";" antes de la llave "{" debes quitarlo, if(DOMINATOR.equals("hola")==true);{

Comment: Como comentario, `DOMINATOR.equals("hola")==true` puede reducirse a `DOMINATOR.equals("hola")`. pues el método `equals` devuelve un booleano, hacer la comparación `== true` es totalmente innecesario y aumenta el número de operaciones que hace la máquina

Comment: gracias crap, errores de principiantes, osea yo

Answer (score 3):

tienes un ; de mas en el if prueba así:(formatee un poco tu código) también puedes quitar ese true, es mas que todo por estética y buenas practicas, te aconsejaría que también leyeras un poco sobre ese tema :)
y te quedaria algo asi el codigo:

```
Scanner entra=new Scanner(System.in);
String DOMINATOR=entra.nextLine();
System.out.println("Le puedo ayudar en algo buen pana");
DOMINATOR=entra.nextLine();

if(DOMINATOR.equals("hola"))
  System.out.println("bueno");
else
  System.out.println("esta mal");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String DOMINATOR=entra.nextLine();
System.out.println("Le puedo ayudar en algo buen pana");
DOMINATOR=entra.nextLine();
   if(DOMINATOR.equals("hola")==true){
       System.out.println("bueno");
   }else{
System.out.println("esta mal");
}
```

Comment: por favor explica tu codigo

Comment: Tienes estructura incorrecta en el IF en la primera condición posees un `;` al final `if(DOMINATOR.equals("hola")==true);{` lo correcto `if(DOMINATOR.equals("hola")==true){`